# Update values in jsonfield for particular keys

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm, django-jsonfield

I have JSONField in my model with following structure:

```
{
    "1":
        {
            ...
            "is_disabled": false
        },
    "2":
        {
            ...
            "is_disabled": false
        },
    "3":
        {
            ...
            "is_disabled": false
        }
}
```

And I have set of pks like:

```
pk_set = {1, 2}
```

How can i update `"is_disabled"` key to `true` only for pks in `pk_set` in single query?

Comment: Looks like pretty regular python dictionary, what have you tried?

Comment: It's not a regular python dict, it's a JSONField in django models.
And i want to create one query rather iterating through pk_set.

Comment: Oh, if you wanted to do that with single query please include that in your question, because technically you could iterate over every object and then for every dict value in pk set update is_disabled and save